# Drawing maps with d3.js which contains cities

Tags: d3.js, maps, geojson

I intend to draw maps using d3.js and geoJson.
I need to plot circles on this map.These circles when hovered should get bigger and display some data inside that.

Also,i need to create a time line scale which will increase and decrease the circles in the map based on the data for that particular time frame.

I am able to draw map with the help of geo JSON file but the problem is how to plot the circles such that when map is moved in the canvass the circle remains at same position inside the map.I mean the circles should be relative to map not relative to canvass.

Secondly I am not able to understand how the coordinate system of maps work.

Any help Please..

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/)?

Comment: I have gone through many tutorials of selectors,joins,transitions but could not find One which would help me in solving the problem.Also I am not able to understand how we are able to draw map using geoJson data.

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.schneidy.com/Tutorials/MapsTutorial.html) may also help.

Comment: the circles have latitude and longitude stored in a separate file or are they in the same json?

Comment: Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 13.942798456012184, 47.166343140041839 ], [ 14.021737228712404, 47.170883865905125 ]..I hope these are coordinates ,right?and these 3d coordinates are converted into 2d coordinates by projection?The circles which I will be drawing could be cities or could not be.In case of cities I can get the 3d coordinates ,but in other case how can I find out the oordinates?Secondly I am adding zooming functionality, in that case circles should also scale in accordance to map and re adjust according to new size of map.Please help me out.